# Pet Troll in Torchlight

Tags: torchlight

The first fishing hole I ran into gave me a fish that turned my pet into an Troll (permanently). This was great because now my pet was hardcore and never took enough damage to start fleeing.

Later on I used a Bat Fish on him just to see what he would look like and how he would act if he was one of those little demons. After 120 seconds he turned back to his original self (not a Troll).

I have tried and tried to get that fish again, but to no avail. Does that fish only show up only once? If you can get it more than once, is there a particular fishing spot that produces more of them?

As a side question, what is the name of that fish?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 3 sizes of pet-consumable fish:

- **Regular** fish transform your pet for 2 minutes and are fairly common.
- **Big** fish transform your pet for 1 hour and appear about 1/10 as often as regular fish.
- **Giant** fish transform your pet *permanently* and appear about 1/200 as often as regular fish.

The rarity of pet-consumable fishes are not affected by the tileset (crypt, mines, ruins, palace, etc) you're fishing in. (Character-consumable fishes are, however)

You can find a list of pet-consumable fish [here on StrategyWiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Torchlight/Fish#Pet-consumable_fish). I don't see one that transforms your pet into an ogre...was it actually a [Varkolyn](http://www.google.ca/images?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=PAb&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=varkolyn&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1093&bih=750)?

Comment: So basically I just need some more dedication and patience? Thanks for clearing up my fishing confusion... I was beginning to think it was just not possible to get that fish twice. And yes it was a Varkolyn I just liked calling him an ogre :P.

Comment: There's an excellent mod out there called FishMash that lets you turn any 5 fish into a single larger one. It makes getting the transformation you want a lot easier. (I haven't used it for a long time though, and it looks like it might be defunct)

Comment: I want to add it's not a Varkolyn it was a troll... found it after reading the strategy wiki you linked, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The fish that turns you into a troll perm was given to each of my characters at the start of game. Try making a new character just to put the fish in the shared stash to get your perm troll again. It worked for me on 360.

Comment: hmm I don't remember starting with it and I'm playing on 360 too... but then again I don't remember catching it either I just noticed it in there after fishing in the first spot. I'll give it a shot and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

It’s the improbably large fish.[image]